# Convert "Parquet" file format to CSV and Polygon shapefile to open in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: convert

I have a community boundary parquet file format from https://overturemaps.org/ website. I need to convert the "Parquet" file format to CSV and the polygon shapefile to open in ArcGIS Pro.
Do you have any idea to use FME? or Python or GIS tools?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Kindly ask one problem per question either python or ArcGIS pro.

Comment: fyi GeoParquet is supported at  FME 2023.1.0.0 b23593 20230810
------------------------------
[Add] New Format: Apache GeoParquet Reader/Writer  https://downloads.safe.com/fme/2023/platform_independent/whatsnew_2023_1.txt

Comment: GDAL support parquet since 3.5.0  (and QGIS build with GDAL 3.5.0 or later inherit  parquet support)

Answer (score 1):

Parquet is supported in ArcGIS Pro via the multifile feature connection (mfc).
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/big-data-connections/big-data-connections.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1E8F881AD353430E82F92B0FFB7A939F

New in ArcGIS Pro 3.2, these parquet-based mfc datasets can be added to the map and used in most geoprocessing tools. In previous releases, the parquet-based mfc datasets could only be used with GeoAnalytics Desktop tools (Advanced license) including "Copy Dataset From Multifile Feature Connection", which will convert the mfc dataset to any of numerous formats supported by ArcGIS.